# when i train a model with different input format(numpy array and dataframe),i get different model performance?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I tried to perform loaasCV based on two different input type but in same shape.When i uesd the dataframe as input,it perform normally but runtime is very long. But when i change the format into numpy array, the lassoCV always choose the maximum value of the trainable parameters of alphas.For example, i set the trainable as np.logsapce(-3,5,100),the model with dataframe format input will choose a value like 0.0045,0.48,0001 etc, but the numpy array format input will choose 10**5, which is the maximum number of the range? I prefer to use array format as input because it's runtime is much faster.

Comment: Unless the model is specically designed for pandas, it probably first converts the frame to array, e.g. `np.array(df)` or equivalently `df.to_numpy()`.  Compare the shape and dtype of the array alternatives.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.